# Can I power something directly from an IC, for example a little relay?

Tags: voltage, motor, relay, integrated-circuit

I am trying to design a tiny circuit to control a DC motor using buttons.

The motor needs 12 volts to move in one direction and -12 volts to move in the other.

The design I came up with is in this picture:

[image]

The special added component is a relay with this lay out:

- Vin - NC
- GND - COMM
- / - NO

The top left relay is to turn the whole system off. The top right is to prevent short circuits. The bottom 2 special two state relays are to switch the direction of the voltage.

The problem is that I do not know if I can connect the XOR gate on an IC directly to a power using object (the relay.)

Also, do I need to place a resistor in series with the relay becouse it is essentially a coil? (I know that coils act as a short after a long time of DC current.)

If there is a better and easier way to achieve this function, I would be very interested.

Comment: If the XOR gate can power it or not, depends on the current consumption of the relay and the output capability of the XOR gate. So you would need to provide us a datasheet to give you an answer for that. 

If you supply the DC relay with a coil voltage within its specification you will not need any series resistor. I would however place a flyback diode across the coil

Comment: "IC" could mean anything, so the question is completely unclear. You are essentially asking if you can power a relay with unknown characteristics from a "thingie".

Answer (score 2):

If Relay0 is a [reed relay,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed_relay) then it might work.  Reed relays are available with coils that only draw a few milliamperes.

You'll need to look at the datasheet of your XOR IC, find out how much current it can deliver, then find a reed relay that can operate on that current and the supply voltage of your IC.

The more typical way to do this is to use a single transistor from the output of the XOR to drive the coils of your relays.

This circuit shows how to drive a motor safely from a digital IC:

[image]

The [original answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/91295/47070) I borrowed that from explains the details.

You can use the same circuit to drive your relay.

---

Regardless of which circuit you use, you **need** the diode as shown across the motor.  Turning off a motor or relay coil causes high voltage spikes that can kill your processor, digital IC, or transistor.

Comment: This is as much help as you can get with the information provided. Good answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The answer was very clear and educational.
I will certainly add the diode for protection

Answer (score 0):

If you use solid state relays you can of course do it.

Suppose you are using a mechanical relay. If we look at very small relay (like [Coto 9900](https://disti-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/testco-inc/files/datasheets/14187.pdf)) we see that the operating voltage is 3,8-5,0V with the coil resistance 150Omh. Which gives to us 25-33mA coil current.

According to the pg.206 of the [PIC16F877A datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/39582b.pdf) we can get up to 25mA from single pin at a voltage of 1,5-3,3V (with nominal MCU power voltage of the 5,0V).

So I think you cannot reliably power any mechanical relay directly from a single pin of something like a MCU IC.

But there is one bad (but working) practice.

According to the pg.175 [PIC16F877A datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/39582b.pdf) you can get up to 200mA by combining several pins.

Answer (score 0):

Only one relay would suffice for the required function.

[image]

Comment: This circuit is clearly better than my amateur one, Thank you for the simple solution. I made a assumption though, because I dont fully understand the schematic. The part in the right bottom corner with the S--R. I assumed these are the coils of the relays, am I right about this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Anytime, Siebe Arnout! It's a single latch relay with two coils (set & reset). A single pulse to the set coil (pressing & releasing the push button) latches the relay till a single pulse to the reset coil unlatches it.